# Variable declaration methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, declaration

I have seen the following code in a website...
what does this mean?.Can i declare variables in the format variableName : value instead of variableName = value.

```
     if (!window.Node){
       var Node =
      {
        ELEMENT_NODE                :  1,
        ATTRIBUTE_NODE              :  2,
        TEXT_NODE                   :  3,
        CDATA_SECTION_NODE          :  4,
        ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE       :  5,
        ENTITY_NODE                 :  6,
        PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE :  7,
        COMMENT_NODE                :  8,
        DOCUMENT_NODE               :  9,
        DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE          : 10,
        DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE      : 11,
        NOTATION_NODE               : 12
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are object properties in an object litteral.

Empty object litteral:

```
var obj = {};
```

With properties:

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    test: 123
};
```

You can then access properties this way:

```
alert(obj.foo);
```

Note that this notation only works inside of object litterals. If you want to set a property from outside, also use the dot notation:

```
obj.foo = "hi";
```

Answer (score 1):

its an Object Literal.

Follow some tutorials,you'll understand more..
Here's a small tutorial

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

Comment: When we define classes we use this keyword followed by the property name.Can i use the literal notation there

Comment: if the object tat you are trying to access is defined as a literal,then you can use `obj.propName` , look at Xeon06 's answer,he's given a brief.. SPEND SOME TIME ON GOOGLE before posting questions here,u wont have such doubts..

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
if (!window.Node){
```

Means, if the `Node` variable doesn't yet exist, then do the following:

`Node` is initialized to an [object literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php) (basically a hash table).  For example:

`Node['ENTITY_NODE']` is equal to 6.

This can also be expressed as `Node.ENTITY_NODE` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `variableName: value` format is what is used to statically declare javascript properties of an object.  In your example, `Node` is a new object and they are declaring 12 properties for it.  You can do that too for property declarations, but property declarations are not exactly the same thing as a variable declaration.

What this code means is: "if `window.Node` doesn't already exist, then declare it as an object with these 12 properties".

It can then be accessed like this:

```
Node.ELEMENT_NODE == 1
```

The actual purpose of this code is to make sure that these node values are declared once and only once in a given web app so that they can be used by relevant code using meaningful symbol names rather than just comparing to a number.